# Genre of "Bourbon Street" (Tuohy), "Save My Soul" (Big Bad Voodoo Daddy), more

Tags: identify-this-genre, similar-artists, genre-characteristics

Looking for genre names so I can find more music like these, if you have recommendations, they're more than welcome. I NEED MORE MUSIC

These first two are pretty similar:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kQSFyq6mac Bourbon Street by Jeff Tuohy

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5IEt63qOSI Save my Soul by Big Bad Voodoo Daddy

Next there's this cover of Seven Nation Army that I'm in LOVE with. I would very much like to know what this vocal style is called.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sB6HY8r983c

Answer (score 3):

These songs are all modern variations on the early jazz styles that came out of New Orleans in the 1920s and 30s.  The vocal style is "jazz singing" or "[vocal jazz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_jazz)".  [Billie Holiday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRYFRvOUrvI) is usually considered the best-ever jazz singer.  [Diana Krall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J9bwNLRiJU) is a popular modern jazz singer.  As the video itself notes, this particular song is in the style of a New Orleans' dirge, the more somber of the two traditional accompaniments to the distinctive [New Orleans style funeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazz_funeral).

Some good search terms are "hot jazz", "Dixieland" and "swing," optionally with the modifier "modern."  You can also try "neo-swing" and "swing revival."

Here are some sample results with those search terms:

- [hot jazz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yD58ZyWdXs&list=PLiYGj-YN1hNLa-_BCTsLSNDVgK_oqlMlF)
- [modern hot jazz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJLDO8Id-9I)
- [modern Dixieland](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMEdYy2G-9Y)
- [swing revival / neo swing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dFiiJPy1As&list=PLu2YYNcnF9bjXrX9eJSdjmYZqEZ-IW27z)