# Genre of music favored on "Lucifer" tv show

Tags: rock, identify-this-genre, guitar

*Note: This was moved from [another question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/genre-of-bourbon-street-tuohy-save-my-soul-big-bad-voodoo-daddy-more) by @JasmineMcShea to avoid having two separate questions in the same post.*

> [Trying to find a better genre description for] what I THINK is Rock'n'Roll, not sure, found most of it on a TV show called *Lucifer* (good show btw) he called it devil music,
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYJ1IrxDLPM Sinister Kid by The Black Keys
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3VGbIpCFSA Sweet Providing Woman by Paul Otten
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0E4KmSgUM4 Dangerous by Royal Deluxe
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBtPrNZdvfg Hipster Shakes by Black Pistol Fire
>
> I know most of these all have a vintage feel to them, even the more modern ones have a guitar sound the feels very vintage and I'm in love. What's that guitar sound called btw?
>
> Please help fuel my addiction.

Answer (score 2):

These are modern 'garage rock' influenced bands. Garage rock has influence from rhythm & blues, punk rock, and traditional rock-n-roll. The mainstream success of 00's bands like the white stripes, the hives, the vines, the strokes, and the black keys popularized the genre.

Modern Pop-rock/Modern rock would be what I consider your examples. It owes a lot to the 'garage rock' revival of the 00's, but goes for a more polished and produced sound, and with more pop influenced composition and hooks. The Arctic Monkeys or Royal Deluxe would be a good example of modern pop-rock. Comparing the Black Keys albums Rubber Factory or Thickfreakness to Brothers is also a good comparison of the subtle difference.